# Copy string to two dimensional char array using strncpy

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a variable, the string `temp`;

`temp`'s value is some string, and it is in a loop and value keeps on changing.

I need to have a backup for the strings present in the `temp` variable using the variable:

```
char asset[8][256]
```

I tried using:

```
strncpy(&asset[8][256], temp.c_str(), 256)
```

But it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work? do you get error output? If so please update your question with the exact output you get.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `strncpy` is an accident waiting to happen. Read its specification carefully: it's not a "safe" `strcpy`, because it will quietly leave you with an unterminated string if the input is too large.

Comment: Think a moment, and have a chance for you to answer your own question:  -- `strncpy(&asset[8][256], temp.c_str(), 256)`  --  You say you wrote a loop.  So how is calling the same, exact, line of code supposed to work inside the loop without something on that line varying in some way?

Answer (score 1):

You say you wrote a loop, but how is that line of code you have supposed to work if you're writing to the same (illegal by the way) address each time?

The loop should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    //...
    strcpy(&asset[i][0], temp.c_str(), 256);
    //...
}
```

You want to write to `&asset[0][0]`, `&asset[1][0]`, `&asset[2][0]`, etc.  Writing to `&asset[8][256]` starts to write the string at that location `[8][256]`, which is out of bounds.

Second, if you want a "backup" of the strings, why are you using arrays?  Why not a `std::vector<std::string>` and just `push_back` the value you want backed up?

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<std::string> asset;
std::string temp;
//...
asset.push_back(temp);  // backs up temp.
```

Not only is this much easier, you are not limited to 8 strings, and there is no chance of a buffer overflow.

Comment: Ya ,thanks Paul for the Answer any how I got it resolved using snprintf function I was using snprintf(asset[assetIDCount],256,"%s",temp.c_str()); where assetIDCount is incremental value less than 8.Thanks for the Help .